# Android java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

Tags: android, android-ndk

i am trying to access to some hikvision cctv cameras.
I have got the so files and the jar files.
when i try to run the program it says

```
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/idonic.mobileapp.androidhikvision-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/idonic.mobileapp.androidhikvision-1/lib/arm, /data/app/idonic.mobileapp.androidhikvision-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libMPCtrl.so"
                                                                                   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
                                                                                   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
                                                                                   at org.MediaPlayer.PlayM4.Player.<clinit>(Player.java:775)
                                                                                   at idonic.mobileapp.androidhikvision.PlayBackByTime$LoadingDevicesTask.doInBackground(PlayBackByTime.java:80)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                                                   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The error occurs when i try to call

```
 player = Player.getInstance();
```

this is the current structure of my program

[image: Current structure]

The error says it cannot find the path in some folder that is not my project so i think i am missing some thing.
maybe i need to declare the new folder where the so files are located.

this is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "idonic.mobileapp.androidhikvision"
    minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags "-frtti -fexceptions"
        }
    }
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a"

    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
 }
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['jniLibs']
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile files('libs/HCNetSDK.jar')
compile files('libs/PlayerSDK.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I am testing in a xiaomi redmi note 4 with android 6/MIUI8.5.3.0.
The gradle version is 2.3 and android studio is 3.0.
i have try to load the project in other devices and in the device with android 5.0 the code works and i can see image from the cctv camera.
the other devices were and s7 with android 7.1.
What i am missing....
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same problem after using the latest Android version > 25. Here is how i fixed the problem.

1. create three folder under app/jniLibs

   a. app/jniLibs/x86
   b. app/jniLibs/armeabi
   c. app/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a

As shown in the picture below
[Add folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmJBL.png)

2. Create a gradle.properties file under rood folder. Right click on the root of the folder, which would be 99% **app** folder > New file > name it gradle.properties
3. Paste the following line

   android.useDeprecatedNdk=true   -> [gradle.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d531.png)
4. Add following lines inside build.gradle(Module: app)

> ```
> android{
>  ....
> defaultConfig{
>     ndk {
>         abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi"
>     }
>  ....
> }
> ```

4. Run the app with you finger crossed.

Comment: Great Man u save my day

Answer (score 0):

I also got into this problem, and I had to add also this in App Manifest file:

```
<application
    android:extractNativeLibs="true" ...
```

Always use the last technical advice: keep you finger crossed.